# Aptana Studio 3

Tags: php, browser, aptana

File1.php,
Has nothing but phpinfo();. I run it as PHP Server and it works great.
File2.php,
Created the same way but but different php codes. The browser opens up and nothing shows up.

You would think File2.php has an error BUT.
-I run File2.php in another place and it works great. 
-I renamed File2.php to File2.html and it works great.
-I uploaded File2.php and File2.html to my domain and they both work great.

Basically it's a setting problem in Aptana.  Please help.
Note: File2.php and File2.html both have Javascript, JQUERY (bundle installed)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My db.php file did not have the correct information to my local db Vs my online db. I knew that and thought it will just report the error of unable to connect. Apparently, it decided to not do anything at all since the db.php file did not have the correct information.